# ReactJS Bootstrap Accordion Component not Collapsing?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5, accordion

I am using the exact documentation from the bootstrap website for how to implement a accordion yet it seems to not work. Item one is shown how it is suppose to be, however it is unable to collapse. Similarly, when I click the second and third items they do not expand at all. In all, it seems the functionality is not working.

```
import React from "react";
import { Card, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

export const About = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Row style={{ padding: "1rem" }}>
        <Col lg={12} md={12} xs={12}>
          <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                <button
                  class="accordion-button"
                  type="button"
                  data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                  data-bs-target="#collapseOne"
                  aria-expanded="true"
                  aria-controls="collapseOne"
                >
                  Accordion Item #1
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div
                id="collapseOne"
                class="accordion-collapse collapse show"
                aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                data-bs-parent="#accordionExample"
              >
                <div class="accordion-body">
                  <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It
                  is shown by default
                  <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit
                  overflow.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
                <button
                  class="accordion-button collapsed"
                  type="button"
                  data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                  data-bs-target="#collapseTwo"
                  aria-expanded="false"
                  aria-controls="collapseTwo"
                >
                  Accordion Item #2
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div
                id="collapseTwo"
                class="accordion-collapse collapse"
                aria-labelledby="headingTwo"
                data-bs-parent="#accordionExample"
              >
                <div class="accordion-body">
                  <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It
                  is hidden by default
                  <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit
                  overflow.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
                <button
                  class="accordion-button collapsed"
                  type="button"
                  data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                  data-bs-target="#collapseThree"
                  aria-expanded="false"
                  aria-controls="collapseThree"
                >
                  Accordion Item #3
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div
                id="collapseThree"
                class="accordion-collapse collapse"
                aria-labelledby="headingThree"
                data-bs-parent="#accordionExample"
              >
                <div class="accordion-body">
                  <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It
                  is hidden by default
                  <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit
                  overflow.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
```

Here is the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/#how-it-works